# write unit test case in python for below algorithm

Tags: python, unit-testing, testcase

I have written code but would not understand how to write test cases in python for below program. Can someone provide an example test case?

Thanks in advance. I have tried some samples but I do not understand what parts of the code should be tested as it only pick the company name related with highest price.

```
with open('/home/company_data.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    tup = namedtuple('tup', ['price','year', 'month'])
    d = OrderedDict()
    names = next(reader)[2:]
    for name in names:
     d[name] = tup(0,'year', 'month')
    for row in reader:
        year, month = row[:2]        
        for name, price in zip(names, map(int, row[2:])):    
           if d[name].price < price:     
               d[name] = tup(price, year, month)
```

Comment: Writing a unit test requires that you know what the code is supposed to do. How do you know if a function is working if you don't know what 'working' means?

Comment: Can you make sure that the indentation on the code is correct?

Comment: I know about the working but don't know actually what should be write in test case code.

Comment: @AlexO'Neill : Thanks for notice .made changes.

Comment: In a test case expected value should be compared with value returned by your function, assuming you know what data you've passed to your function.

Comment: @u_mulder: if values are returned dynamically from given raw data so how do i make comparison for writing test cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test cases prove the correctness of your functions. How do you test correctness? By "proving" it. You therefore write test cases against your functions with predefined output so you can verify that it returns the expected result.

Example : Using python's [unittest](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDIQFjAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.python.org%2F2%2Flibrary%2Funittest.html&ei=QMn5VMbzJsOlygOE4oLQBA&usg=AFQjCNGzMB6sVh82IRCQLgc75L-23mFmCg&sig2=HtbQ2XRGECqhOin8LeUjiA&bvm=bv.87611401,d.bGQ) module, you can write a test for a function that adds two numbers like this:

```
import unittest

def my_adding_function(x,y):
    return x+y

class TestMyFunction(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def test_my_function(self):
        self.assertEqual(my_adding_function(3,4), 7)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

What you are doing here is saying when I call my_adding_function on 3 & 4, I should get 7. If your function is correct, the test will pass - and fail if not.

For your case, if you want to pick the company name with the highest price from a sample csv, something like this would do:

```
import unittest

def get_highest_valued_company(input_csv):
    process[...]
    return 'highest company name'

class TestMyFunction(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def test_my_csv_function(self):
        self.assertTrue(get_highest_valued_company(csv)=='name_here')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: thanks for ans with explanation.i have now clear approach regarding test cases .is it required to write:-                 def setUp(self):    . if yes, i am not able to understand . plz explain.

Comment: No, you do not have to include setUp() in your tests. It's a good way to initialize your class, like a constructor. So this is ideally where you would have your initialization variables for this class.

Answer (score 1):

It'd behoove you to make your code as generic as possible. Like in this case change it slightly so it can handle any filename. Something like:

```
def foo(filename):
  with open(filename) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    tup = namedtuple('tup', ['price','year', 'month'])
    d = OrderedDict()
    names = next(reader)[2:]
    for name in names:
     d[name] = tup(0,'year', 'month')
    for row in reader:
        year, month = row[:2]        
        for name, price in zip(names, map(int, row[2:])):    
           if d[name].price < price:     
               d[name] = tup(price, year, month)
    return d
```

Then test with something like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__": #run if standalone
    results = foo('test.csv')
    assert (results == expectedResults)
```

where expectedResults contains what you'd expect the results to look like. "==" may not work exactly but some sort of test for equality. If you use assertions and/or standalone checks you can leave your tests with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Code like this would be difficult to test as there is no output, however you could test that it is picking up the right company by providing it with a sample set of data and checking the company it is selecting against the company you already know has the highest price (you may have to change your code to make it more dynamic for selecting data)

Comment: thank you for giving "clear information" regarding my issue.I want to up-vote ur ans but not having reputation.btw THANKS

Comment: @siddharth No problem :) If it is the answer you're looking for, I believe you can select it as best answer without reputation